# Why this similar two codes make different results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def page_rewrite2
    temp = Db1.find(params[:id])
    temp.content = params[:submit_recontent]
    temp.save
    redirect_to "/contrl1/page_main"
end
```

This code works well.
The content is changed and saved.

```
def page_rewrite2
    Db1.find(params[:id]).content = params[:submit_recontent]
    Db1.find(params[:id]).save
    redirect_to "/contrl1/page_main"
end
```

I think this code also have to work well.
But, this code doesn't work well.
Why this similar two codes make different results?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `Db1.find` method always returns new instance od Db1 class. Two instances might be bound to the same db record, however on the programming level they are different objects. It is pretty much the same as:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :a
end

obj = A.new
obj.a = 4
obj.a #=> 4

A.new.a #=> nil, not 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second case

```
def page_rewrite2
    Db1.find(params[:id]).content = params[:submit_recontent]
    Db1.find(params[:id]).save
    redirect_to "/contrl1/page_main"
end
```

You are first loading the record, assigning some new value to its content.
And later you are loading the record again and saving it. This newly loaded record has no idea that you updated the content in the previous step. Which is why it does not work as you intended.

By assigning the loaded record to a variable, like you did in your first example, that record knows that its content is updated and so it saves that information.